# Why am I getting match is not a function when it is clearly defined?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router

I'm rendering my React App on the server, but I get this error `TypeError: match is not a function`. I have no clue how to fix this or what this error means because react-router docs say other wise.

```
var routes = require('./public/src/routes');
var React = require('react');
var renderToString = require('react-dom/server');
var match = require('react-router');
var RouterContext = require('react-router');

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  match(
    { routes, location: req.url },
     (err, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
       if (err) {
        return res.status(500).send(err.message);
      }
      let markup;
      if(renderProps) {
        markup = renderToString(React.createElement(RoutingContext, renderProps));
      }
      return res.render('index', { markup });
     }
  )
})
```

Comment: Where exactly do you see `match` imported here? https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router It's pretty obvious in the docs that `react-router` does not export a function. Also look at `var match = require('react-router'); var RouterContext = require('react-router');`. It seems you are expecting `require('react-router')` to return a different value each it is called. That doesn't make sense. `require('react-router')` will always return the same value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're assigning `match` to the module `react-router` itself, which is not a function and is not what you want to do. `match` is a *part* of the module, not the module itself. The same goes for `RouterContext`. What you have to do is:

```
var match = require("react-router").match;
var RouterContext = require("react-router").RouterContext;
```

This requires the correct module and assigns `match` correctly to the function from the module. The same is done for `RouterContext`. Alternatively, with ES6's new destructuring assignment (it's equivalent):

```
var { match, RouterContext } = require("react-router");
```

Comment: @joethemow Also note that destructuring assignment is something new in ES6. Your configuration may not support it.